# node.js: How asynchronous are Async loops really?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I want to iterate an array asynchronously to unblock the execution. I'm using caolan/async to achieve that. When testing this code:

```
var ASync = require('async');

var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
}

var buf = "howdy";
ASync.forEach(arr, function(item, callback) {
    buf += item;
    callback();
}, function(err) {
    console.log(buf); // in the end
});
buf += "finished";
```

it shows this result:

```
howdy0123456789
```

I would assume it **should** show

```
howdyfinished0123456789
```

since I expect the Async lib to defer the execution. But why it isn't?

Comment: Some answers on that topic I read here suggest to use a `setTimeout(...,0)` workaround to hand back execution to the main event loop but I really don't like the idea - going that way you could actually use JS' built-in `Array.forEach` method anyway. Besides, I'd expect that the Async module would do that if necessary and hide those details from me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `callback` is executed on the same event loop iteration as `foreach` itself. As you never go outside of the current event loop iteration, `buf += "finished"` only executes after all `buf += item` were executed.

The proper version is

```
var ASync = require('async');

var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
}

var buf = "howdy";
ASync.forEach(arr, function(item, callback) {
    process.nextTick(function () {
        buf += item;
        callback();
    });
}, function(err) {
    console.log(buf); // in the end
});
buf += "finished";
```

In the end, the `buf` will equal to `howdy0finished123456789`.

However, this task is oversimplified. Why does one need the async loop at all?

1. To perform async tasks in parallel. First, as each task is async, you won't trigger the `callback` in the same event loop iteration anyway, rather giving it to the specific async task. Second, `async.parallel` is more suitable for this kind of task.
2. To perform some CPU-intensive tasks, avoiding freezing the event loop (so that Node could process some tasks in between the iterations). This is what I'm assuming in my code example above. It would be quite hard to achieve this task using the plain JS (and its build-in `Array.prototype.forEach`), as you need to implement in some way the detection of the event all iterations of the loop has been processed.

Comment: great, but isn't the "tick handling" exactly what a library like Async should hide from the user? What is the advantage of the iteration functions in Async anyway then: the `forEach` method on the `Array` prototype is doing well in this case,too... Is Step.js doing "better"?

Comment: `async` hides from you the logic of detection of the event all tasks are done. If you want to offload some specific portion of your task to another iteration of event loop, state it explicitly; it is not a big deal.

Comment: Under the hood, `async` uses built-in `Array.prototype.forEach`. You can see what the `async` adds here: https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L79

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read this:
http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick